# Attempting to perform Integration Test with Spring Data JPA Repositories returns NullPointerException

Tags: spring, testing, repository, integration, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to write integration tests for a Spring 4 MVC project. In the project I am using Spring Data JPA Repositories and Hibernate.

Below are two files, the Integration Test itself and the Configuration for setting up my Persistence configuration.

**PersistenceTestConfiguration.java**

```
package <project>.cms.rest.test.configuration;

import <project>.cms.rest.entity.EntityMarker;
import <project>.cms.rest.repository.RepositoryMarker;
import org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEStringEncryptor;
import org.jasypt.hibernate3.encryptor.HibernatePBEEncryptorRegistry;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabase;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseType;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateExceptionTranslator;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = {RepositoryMarker.class})
public class PersistenceTestConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() throws NamingException {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(false);
        vendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan(EntityMarker.class.getPackage().getName());
        factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
        return factoryBean.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() throws NamingException {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateExceptionTranslator exceptionTranslator() {
        return new HibernateExceptionTranslator();
    }

    @Bean
    public EmbeddedDatabase dataSource() {
        EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
        return builder.setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2).build();
    }
}
```

The issue I'm having is that although my PersistenceTestConfiguration class should be instantiating the appropriate Repositories - they are coming through into the service classes as null.

If I manually @Mock the repositories in the Test Class then they are no longer null in the services, but will always return null on for example calling the .save(entity) method.

I suspect I'm doing something obviously stupid but can't seem to figure it out.

Any pointers in the right direction would be kindly appreciated.

Edit 1:

**Simplest Possible Test**

```
package <project>.cms.rest.test.service;

import <project>.cms.rest.resource.PostalAddressResource;
import <project>.cms.rest.service.PostalAddressService;
import <project>.cms.rest.service.impl.PostalAddressServiceImpl;
import <project>.cms.rest.test.configuration.PersistenceTestConfiguration;
import liquibase.Liquibase;
import liquibase.database.jvm.JdbcConnection;
import liquibase.exception.LiquibaseException;
import liquibase.resource.FileSystemResourceAccessor;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabase;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestExecutionListeners;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.support.AnnotationConfigContextLoader;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.util.Assert;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import java.sql.Connection;

@Transactional
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class, classes = { PersistenceTestConfiguration.class })
@TestExecutionListeners(mergeMode = TestExecutionListeners.MergeMode.MERGE_WITH_DEFAULTS)
public class PostalAddressServiceIntegrationTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private PostalAddressService postalAddressService = new PostalAddressServiceImpl();

    @Inject
    private EmbeddedDatabase database;

    @Before
    public void setupDatabase() throws java.sql.SQLException, LiquibaseException {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        Liquibase liquibase = new Liquibase(
                "src/liquibase/liquibase-master.xml",
                new FileSystemResourceAccessor(),
                new JdbcConnection(database.getConnection())
        );

        liquibase.update("");
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws java.sql.SQLException, LiquibaseException {
        Connection connection = database.getConnection();
        JdbcConnection liquibaseConnection = new JdbcConnection(connection);

        Liquibase liquibase = new Liquibase(
                "src/liquibase/liquibase-master.xml",
                new FileSystemResourceAccessor(),
                liquibaseConnection
        );

        liquibase.dropAll();
    }

    @Test
    public void testAddNewPostalAddress() {
        PostalAddressResource postalAddressResource = new PostalAddressResource();

        postalAddressResource.setBuildingNameOrNumber("1");
        postalAddressResource.setFirstLine("Test Lane");
        postalAddressResource.setSecondLine("Testville");
        postalAddressResource.setCountry("Testshire");
        postalAddressResource.setPostCode("TE5 7ER");
        postalAddressResource.setCountry("United Kingdom");

        PostalAddressResource result = postalAddressService.createPostalAddress(postalAddressResource);

        Assert.notNull(result);
    }
}
```

**Resulting Stack Trace**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at <project>.cms.rest.service.impl.PostalAddressServiceImpl.createPostalAddress(PostalAddressServiceImpl.java:66)
    at <project>.cms.rest.test.service.PostalAddressServiceIntegrationTest.testAddNewPostalAddress(PostalAddressServiceIntegrationTest.java:78)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:254)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68)
```

Line 66 of PostalAddressServiceImpl is as follows:

```
} while(repository.countByPublicId(publicId) > 0);
```

Edit 2:

Creating a test that works directly with the Repository rather than via the Service works, having:

```
@Inject
private PostalAddressRepository repository;
```

at the top behaves itself.

So it seems to be when @InjectMocks is supposed to be wiring up the dependencies of the Service class that there is an issue, resulting in the repository being null.

Comment: Without a stack trace it's hard to tell anything. Have one handy? Also, it usually helps to break down the reproducing example more to make sure it's not one of the dozens of pieces that are in play here causing the issue. Does a plain repository bootstrap (without all the security, services etc.) in play cause the same issue?

Comment: @OliverGierke The stack trace is simply just showing that the repository in use by the service is null when I call a method on it. Nothing within the Spring code at all. I'll try to narrow this down to a single working example but there isn't much else to strip out

Comment: I'm sorry but without further information or a more reduced example it's hard to find out what's going wrong as it virtually could be anything.

Comment: @OliverGierke Have edited my question with the simplest possible Test class I can think of - and provided an example stack trace

Comment: I'm sorry again, but there's still ton of addition injections. What's got Liquibase to do with this? There's 3 test cases, not one. We don't even null at which of the lines the NPE occurs as there's still no stack trace. Sorry, but you won't find anyone remotely being able to help you this way.

Comment: @OliverGierke If you look back at the question you will see at the bottom, I have provided a single test, the stack trace, and the line that the NPE is thrown on. Liquibase is required in order to have a database schema that the repository can work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been resolved as per:

https://tedvinke.wordpress.com/2014/02/13/mockito-why-you-should-not-use-injectmocks-annotation-to-autowire-fields/

Changing my services to have constructors to take in the dependencies, rather than hoping @InjectMocks will do the job it's supposed to do instead.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at what I've got to run something similar, I also have a loader defined like this

```
@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class,
```

and some test listeners

```
@TestExecutionListeners({DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class, TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class})
```

Integration testing is a bit messy in Spring but has been tidied up a lot in Spring Boot 1.4:

https://spring.io/blog/2016/04/15/testing-improvements-in-spring-boot-1-4

Comment: Thanks for this - had attempted to use each of these annotations but separately to no avail. Have just tried now, and the repositories are still null within the Services. Should I be @Mock'ing the repositories (I suspect no)? Sadly not in a position to move to Spring Boot on this project yet.

Comment: Has the configuration you're pulling in got things like @EnableJpaRepositories on it ?

Comment: I have the configuration included in my original post - I have these annotations at the top: Configuration, EnableTransactionManagement , EnableJpaRepositores and now TestExecutionListeners